# wp_mail() sending twice to each mail in foreach?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, wp-mail

I am sending mails via `wp_mail` inside a `foreach` loop.
It works fine but after 20 minutes or so the mails are sent again?

This is my function (I am running it on save product variation of WooCommerce):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'bbloomer_save_custom_field_variations', 10, 2 );
function bbloomer_save_custom_field_variations( $variation_id, $i ) {
  $arrayEmails = array(
   'myemail@test.nl',
   'myemail@test.nl',
   'myemail@test.nl',
   'myemail@test.nl',
   'myemail@test.nl',
  )

  $headers[] = 'From: Mail sender <info@mailsender.nl>';
  foreach($arrayEmails as $email) {
    wp_mail( $email, 'Mail subject', '<p>This is the mail content</p>', $headers );
  }
  die();
}
```

I receive the mail 5 times which is correct. But later I receive the mails again?

Comment: Probably because someone saved the variation again ...?

Comment: Why are you putting `die();` at the end of your callback function here? I very much doubt it makes sense to exit the process of saving a product variation at this point.